# LINQ Having Clause with inner select

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

How would the following be converted to `LINQ`-`EF`

```
select Name
from TableA as TableAOuter
group by TableAOuter.Name, TableAOuter.Id
having(
    select count(TableAInner.Id)
    from TableA as TableAInner
    where TAbleAInner.Reference=TableAOuter.Id) = 0
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, that looks like:

```
var query = from row in tableOuter
            group row by new { row.Name, row.Id } into g
            where !tableInner.Any(inner => inner.Reference == g.Key.Id)
            select g.Key.Name;
```

Although I'd be tempted to perform the filtering before the grouping - at which point you can just group the row name:

```
var query = from row in tableOuter
            where !tableInner.Any(row => inner.Reference == row.Id)
            group row.Name by new { row.Name, row.Id };
```

I *think* that should do the same thing, right?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `!tableInner.Any(inner => inner.Reference == row.Id)` and `group row.Name by new`?

Comment: Whoops - I meant "group row by" in both cases. In the first version you can't use `row.Id` in the where clause because it's not in scope. Fixed both and simplified the latter approach.